# How to select pairs by keys and transform them to map?

Tags: scala, collections

Suppose I have got a list of key-value pairs of type `List[(Int, String)]` and a set of keys of type `Set[Int]`. I am writing a function to return a map `Map[Int, String]`, which contains all keys from the given set and only those keys. If the pairs don't contain all the keys or contain duplicate keys then return an error.

For simplicity I return `Option` here: `Some` for success and `None` for failure.

```
def foo(pairs: List[(Int, String)], keys: Set[Int]): Option[Map[Int, String]] = {
  val m = pairs.groupBy(_._1).filterKeys(keys)
  if (m.keys != keys || m.exists(_._2.size != 1)) None else Some(m.mapValues(_.head._2))
}
```

The code above is probably working but looks clumsy. How would you improve it ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
  def foo(pairs: List[(Int, String)], keys: Set[Int]): Option[Map[Int, String]] = {
    val m = pairs.toMap
    keys.subsetOf(m.keys.toSet) && m.size == pairs.size match {
      case true =>  Some(m.filterKeys(keys))
      case false => None
    }
  }
```

Use `subsetOf` to check whether `keys` is `subset` of **map.keys**.

Comment: Thanks. Did you check if `pairs` has duplicate keys ?

Comment: How about `&& m.size == pairs.size` to compare the size